# Решение системы уравнений с двумя неизвестными

Tags: javascript, java

Проблема с решением системы уравнений с двумя переменными. Какая-то очевидная моя ошибка на `Java`, но на `JS` все прекрасно работает. Самая простая система уравнений. Допустим, что коэффициенты равны 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 и 6. Правильный ответ: -1 и 2. Но на `Java` выходит -4 и 3.5. Для понимания - формат системы уравнений:

```
ax + by = c
dx + ey = f
```

На `JS`:

```
    function solver(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
        var y = (a * f - c * d) / (a * e - b * d)
        var x = (c * e - b * f) / (a * e - b * d)
        return x + " " + y
    }
```

На `Java`:

```
    public static String eqSolver(double a, double b, double c, double d, double f, double e){
        double y = (a * f - c * d) / (a * e - b * d);
        double x = (c * e - b * f) / (a * e - b * d);
        return x + " " + y;
    }
```

Помогите. Пожалуйста!

Comment: У вас в Java-коде порядок аргументов функции другой.

Comment: Не рекомендуется такие вещи вычислять на double. Рекомедуется использовать BigDecimal.